# SQLite GUI for my grandma

Tags: mac, database, sqlite

I created a SQLite database for my grandmother to store all her poems because I was tired to see her search/copy/paste across many different Word documents. Yet I have still to convince her to use it.

The crucial thing is to find a very basic & very simple GUI to access the database on a Mac.

She will ALMOST EXCLUSIVELY need to:

- Add records to the database through an intuitive interface (by intuitive I mean just few buttons and form view, and no way to get lost in complicated interfaces for creating triggers)
- Search the records with easy to set filters (by table or by field)
- Edit records

She will NOT need to:

- Change the database structure

She might need to (but with easy to understand warnings)

- Delete selected records

I like both `SQLite Manager` for Firfox and `SQLiteStudio` but they have way too many functions for her and she can easily get lost in it without being able to go back to the form-view she will exclusively use.

Is there any app out there that satisfies these requirements?

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that. :-/

Comment: If you're working with sqlite, why not write one from scratch? It'll perfectly meet your views and you can customise it to her needs. I'd add though quite a bit of your problem is user-education related. Change is *hard*.